# express js request problem, pass multiple values/collection for a query key

Tags: node.js, express

I need to pass multiple values i.e a collection for a particular query key in express.

My memory might be tricking me, but I am inclined to believe that I have seen something like this somewhere on the web:

```
http://<somehost>/<somepath>?id[]=10&id[]=11&id[]=12
```

I know that Ruby on Rails returns these `querystring` values as an array but I thought express had some similar `querystring` behaviour but I can't find it in their documentation.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I've found out that it actually works with express.

This querystring

```
http://<somehost>/<somepath>?id[]=10&id[]=11&id[]=12
```

is being parsed into an array by express js. Thus

```
req.query.id => ["10","11","12"]
```

This should be mentioned in the express documentation.

In fact express makes use of a package named 'qs', which is worth taking a closer look at:

https://github.com/ljharb/qs

It even does deep nesting like

```
http://<somehost>/<somepath>?persona[country][birth]=us&person[country][resident]=de
```

which is being parsed into

```
{ person: { country: { birth: 'us', resident: 'de' } } }
```